# Remove repetitive region vcf file using repeatmasker bed file

Tags: vcf, snp, bedtools, repeatmasker, variants

I have a 1000 genomes vcf file for chromosome 14. And I want to remove variants in repetitive regions flagged by repeatMasker. I have a bed file for those repeats. I downloaded that file from UCSC. How can I eliminate/remove those sites in vcf file using repeat masker's bed file? Insights will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple fast alternatives:

```
$ bedops --chrom chr14 -n 1 <(vcf2bed < variants.vcf) <(sort-bed repeats.bed) > answer.bed
$ bedops --chrom chr14 -n 1 <(vcf2bed < variants.vcf) <(rmsk2bed < repeats.rmsk) > answer.bed
```

Using `--chrom chr14` focuses set operations on that chromosome.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks Alex Reynolds

Answer (score 0):

[`vcftools`](https://vcftools.github.io/man_latest.html) with the `--exclude-bed` option or [`bedtools`](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) with the `subtract` command should do the trick.

Comment: how about using bedtools intersect -v?

Comment: probably better to use ``bcftools view -R .bedfile`` - vcftools isn't maintained any more and a fair bit slower than bcftools.